# Metasploit MacOS victim - tools to enable remote desktop / GUI view of the victim

Tags: metasploit, macos, rdp, vnc

If the exploited victim OS is Windows, metasploit has the `getgui` command to run RDP. Then he can manipulate the victim OS through the GUI desktop interface.

```
meterpreter > run getgui -u loneferret -p password
```

([documentation](https://www.offensive-security.com/metasploit-unleashed/enabling-remote-desktop/))

- Is there a similar one-command to setup tool for MacOS victims?
- I know MacOS doesn't support RDP but maybe some metasploit / evilosx modules to set up a VNC connection?
- Or I must do it manually without easy to use scripts?

Answer (score 1):

> **Q1:** Is there a similar one-command to setup tool for MacOS victims? .. or maybe some metasploit / evilosx modules to set up a VNC connection?

You can try to use [vnc_login](https://www.offensive-security.com/metasploit-unleashed/scanner-vnc-auxiliary-modules/) auxiliary scanner to identify if there's available VNC in target and attempt to login with a password or a wordlist:

```
msf > use auxiliary/scanner/vnc/vnc_login
```

And/or [ard_root_pw](https://github.com/rapid7/metasploit-framework/pull/9302) to remotely exploit `CVE-2017-13872` over `5900` port *- if requirements are met*:

```
msf > use auxiliary/scanner/vnc/ard_root_pw
```

> Some notes by `ard_root_pw`'s author ([jgor](https://github.com/jgor)):
>
> > *This extends Rex::Proto::RFB to support usernames, implements authentication security type 30 ("Apple Remote Desktop" / ARD used by macOS), and uses that to add a module to remotely exploit CVE-2017-13872 over 5900/tcp on vulnerable macOS High Sierra hosts that have either Screen Sharing or Remote Management enabled.*
>
> ([source](https://github.com/rapid7/metasploit-framework/pull/9302))

> **Q2:** Or I must do it manually without easy to use scripts?

If you already have access (w/ shell or meterpreter) in target, you should consider that Apple includes a VNC Client by default, you can use it with a ***simple*** bash script:

```
echo '#!/usr/bin/env bash' >> /usr/local/bin/vncviewer
echo open vnc://\$1 >> /usr/local/bin/vncviewer
chmod +x /usr/local/bin/vncviewer
```

After that, *simply* use: `vncviewer [IP]:5901`

([source](https://blog.khairulazam.net/2014/01/11/vncviewer-for-metasploit-payload-on-mac-os-x/))